# Возникла ошибка при попытке собрать проект с помощью Rollup

Tags: javascript, rollup

Работаю через программу Визуал Студио.

[image: Ошибка при попытке собрать проект с помощью Rollup]

Answer (score 0):

В настройках windows разрешите выполнение неподписанных локальных сценариев powershell

[image: Скриншот панели настроек]

Comment: Галочка стоит. Проблема в другом.

Answer (score 0):

Решение найдено. Вдруг кому пригодится.
Проблема в политике безопасности ОС.
Выведете командную строку и наберите сначала команду Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted , потом Y.

Потом попробуйте вернуться к проекту и снова введите rollup -c. Скорее всего выйдет новая, но уже другая ошибка - связано с неправильно указанными путями в rollup.config.
В этом случае добавляем "type": "module" в package.json
после "main": "index.js" (у меня по крайне мере все так прописано)